# is it possible to access already running virtualenv in windows

Tags: django

is it possible to access already running `virtualenv` in windows by external tools ? I need this to run cron like tasks by executing `python manage.py dosometing` of running instance of django. For this I thought I would setup windows task that will execute something like `cmd.exe C:\django\manage.py dosometing` but I dont understand how to do this if django is running inside virtualenv

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. A virtualenv isn't something that runs, it's just a way of setting up environment variables and paths.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can.  The virtualenv is not like a virtual machine, it is not **running**.  The virtualenv is a just a setup where you can have multiple python installations on a single machine.  Each virtualenv lives in a separate directory so you can have different libraries installed, different versions of python etc.  When you 'activate' the virtualenv you are just setting environment variables such as `PATH` which tell python programs which python executables and libraries to use.

So when people say 'Django is running in virtualenv' they just mean django is running.. and there's a virtualenv set up that is controlling which python installation Django is using.

If you look at the virtualenv documentation here: https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/userguide/ ...

It tells you that your activation script is located at:

```
\path\to\env\Scripts\activate
```

Where `\path\to\env` should be replaced by the actual location of your virtualenv.

So, if you are running in a command window, run the activation script first, then all your following commands will be in the virtualenv.  If you're running from the scheduler etc, the easiest thing for you to do is, create a batch file which first runs the activation script, then your django command.  This ensures that you'll always run in the correct virtualenv.

If you really only have one python installation, then technically the virtualenv isn't necessary.. and in that case you could edit your Windows environment variables as follows:

```
VIRTUAL_ENV="/path/to/your/virtualenv"
```

And then also, append to the end of your `Path` variable the path to your python and python scripts directories.  On my system these are:

```
C:\Python27\Scripts;C:\python27\;
```

..and make sure there are no other python directories in your path.

If you open a powershell window and run `env`, it will show you the current settings of your environment variables.  If you do this, run `activate` (in your virtualenv directory) and then run `env` again, comparing the `Path` (and other variables) between the two.. then you'll easily be able to see what `activate` did to your environment, and you can then add that to your Windows configuration.

Then when you run `python myprogram.py` it'll be using the virtualenv without activation.

Comment: Im sorry, but where can I edit VIRTUAL_ENV and PATH variables ?

Comment: I'm on Windows 7 at the moment, it might be a little different in other versions.. but go into 'Control Panel', 'System'.. then click 'Advanced System Settings', then click 'Environment Variables'.  Or, in Windows 7 at least, if you type 'environment' into the search box on the start menu, the options for setting environment variables will come up.

Comment: had only PATH here with C:\Python\Scripts; C:\Python. tried like this https://www.dropbox.com/s/ek05zeqn55fey20/Screenshot%202017-06-09%2022.04.49.png?dl=0 and without activate, but no luck

Comment: Wait.. are you SURE you're using a virtualenv?  One sec let me check one of my machines configuration...

Comment: yes. https://www.dropbox.com/s/7o95d9pkgfjbi06/Screenshot%202017-06-09%2022.10.45.png?dl=0

Comment: Ok.. well, activate sets the environment variables.  So what you could do is open a fresh command window, run `env`, activate, then run `env` again and see what was added.  Then you can do the same in your Windows user or system (depending on what you want) environment variables in order to get the same effect without running activate.  I don't use virtualenv in windows, I use it in linux only.. and in Windows I just do a plain python install.  So there may be some subtle differences.. hence it would be easier to just see what activate changes.

Comment: I've edited the part of my answer related to setting the environment variables, because it wasn't accurate for Windows.  But as I said, check the env before and after activate and that will tell you EXACTLY what you need to change in your environment.:wq

Comment: I try to run command ENV after activation, but virtualenv says that it doesnt know that command :(